# Accepting input in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am starting off withe nodeJS. Here is my code

```
function ask(callback) {
    var stdin = process.stdin, stdout = process.stdout;
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.once('data', function(data) {
        data = data.toString().trim();
        callback(data);
    });
}

ask(function(testcase) {
    ask(function(workers) {
        ask(function(salary) {
            console.log(salary);
        });
    });

});
```

What i would like to do is based on the first input i,e testcase .I would like to run a for loop around the two ask(function(workers)) and ask(function(salary))

```
eg input
2  -- two testcases
2 - num of workers
1 2 - salary / first testcase over
3 -  num of workers
1 2 3 - salary / second - testcase over
```

Now start processing the input. I know nodeJS is aysnchronus and hence even if i place a for loop after the first ask(function(testcase)) . It does not work.

Can anyone guide me as to how to accept inputs in a synchronous manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
function test(testcase) {
    ask(function(workers) {
      ask(function(salary) {
        console.log(salary);

        // Do whatever you want with the data

        // Then:
        ask(test);
      });
    });
}

ask(test);
```

There is no synchronous IO API for the standard input. However, you could read the whole input into a string (until EOF appears), and then process the string in a synchronous manner.